What causes SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync to Always return false?
I am making two factor authentication login and signinManager.TwofactorsignInAsync returns false no matter what I do.. these are my two Actions for two factor login
that is the first part of two facto which creates the code token and send it to user's Email..I deleted checks where user two factor ain't activated
` [HttpPost("Login")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginUserDTO credntials)
        {
            var requiredEmail = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(credntials.Email);
         
            if (requiredEmail.TwoFactorEnabled)
            {
                //enablig twofactor
                //  await userManager.SetTwoFactorEnabledAsync(requiredEmail, true);

                await signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(requiredEmail, credntials.Password, false,      true);

                if (requiredEmail == null || !await userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(requiredEmail, credntials.Password))
                {
                    return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
                    new { Status = "Failed", Message = "Email or Password is incorrect" });


                }
                var twoFactorToken = await userManager.GenerateTwoFactorTokenAsync(requiredEmail, "Email");
                var message = new Message(new string[] { requiredEmail.Email }, "OTP Confirmation", twoFactorToken);
                emailService.SendEmail(message);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, new Models.Response { Status = "Success", Message = $"We have sent an OTP to your Email {requiredEmail.Email}" });

            }

            var expDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
            var token = await GenerateJwtToken(requiredEmail);
            var Message = "User logged in";
            return Ok(new TokenDTO
            {
                Token = token,
                Exp = expDate,
                Message = Message
            });

        }


       `[HttpPost("Logintwo")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> LoginwithOTP(LoginUser2FDTO loginUser2FDTO)
        {
        //      var user = await signInManager.GetTwoFactorAuthenticationUserAsync();
            var requiredEmail = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(loginUser2FDTO.Username);

            var signIn = await signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync("Email", loginUser2FDTO.Code, false, false);

            if (requiredEmail == null)
            {
                var error = new
                {
                    ErrorMessage = "email is not found",
                };
                return Unauthorized(error);
            }
            //  var signIn = await signInManager.TwoFactorSignInAsync(requiredEmail.Email, code, false, false);
            if (signIn.Succeeded)
            {   

                var expDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2);
                var token = await GenerateJwtToken(requiredEmail);
                var Message = "User logged in";
                return Ok(new TokenDTO
                {
                    Token = token,
                    Exp = expDate,
                    Message = Message
                });
            }
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized,
               new { Status = "Failed", Message = "Invalid Code or UserName please re-Login" });

        }`



and this is a snippet from program.cs i think it might be the problem
`
 builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
    options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedPhoneNumber = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

    }
    ).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ITIStore>().AddTokenProvider<EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>>("Email");
`

if any needed anything else. please inform me.

It has possible many reasons. A few situations in my mind are as follows:

Server & Client Time Zone Difference: Time-based One-Time Password authentication depends on both the server and authenticator device having an accurate time.
Default Token Provider Registration: It has been default registration for all flow. It register for data, email and phone provider.
Encode/Decode Step: Some codes includes reserve chars and that are encoded. It may be required decode step.

I hope any of these help you.
